# How to disable item in ComboBox?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I have one ObservableList for two ComboBoxes. When user chooses an item in one of them, I want chosen item to be disabled in the other box and vice versa. In the code below I stuck doing it in one side:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList("first", "second", "third", "forth", "fifth");

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> first;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> second;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        first.getItems().addAll(items);
        second.getItems().addAll(items);

        first.setCellFactory(new Callback<>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> stringListView) {
                return new ListCell<>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(String s, boolean b) {
                        super.updateItem(s, b);
                        if (b)
                            setText(null);
                        else {
                            if (second.getValue() != null) {
                                if (second.getValue().equals(s)) {
                                    setText(s);
                                    setDisable(true);
                                } else setText(s);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I disable item in "first" ComboBox which was chosen in "second" ComboBox?

Comment: why? anyway, a) that's not a task for a cell to decide - let a model have a property and bind the diabled to that property b) what exactly so you want to achieve by _disabled_?

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for your answer. I want to achive that user cannot choose the same item in two ComboBoxes

Comment: repeating: change your modeling (f.i. remove the item if not selectable) - anyway, in problems like this go a step (or several :) back and reduce complexity, here f.i. check whether disabling a cell in a single combo in fact does prevent selection